# grant permission to add/remove members to selected ad group using microsoft graph api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I would like to grant permission to add/remove users to the selected ad groups for azure app. What is the procedure to configure the permission?

Comment: Could you include more details like what commands you tried?

Comment: I have seen the blog that we need to provide GroupMember.ReadWrite.All and Directory.ReadWrite.All. With this permission, I believe that the app can add/remove members of any of the group inside the AD, but I would like to restrict add/remove members only to certain groups not all the groups. Earlier, I have implemented the functionality to restrict access only to read selected mailbox using security enable group.

Answer (score 1):

The permissions required for adding or removing the members from the group are:

Add members:

[image]

Remove Members:
[image]

For restricting the permissions to certain user Application permissions are used by apps that run without a signed-in user present. Hence it is not possible to restrict Microsoft Graph application permission to one specific user account only. Please note that application permissions are full level permissions are granted to app registered in Azure AD.

Please refer this document for more information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts#delegated-and-application-permissions